Understanding the difference in the ideas of standard deviation and coefficient of variation
Question
I am a little bit confused as to why we need a coefficient of variation to understand and compare the "variability" of two data sets. Suppose we have the following two data sets:
A: 1,2,3,4,5
B: 100001,100002,100003,100004,100005
The mean is 3 and 100003, and the standard deviation is the same, which makes complete sense to me as the data sets are consecutive in nature.
But clearly, their coefficient of variations is different, thus "variability" Which quantity does this "variability" correspond to? What exactly does this coefficient of variation signify?
Thoughts
What I can observe is that though 100001 is 2 less than 100003, it's approximately 99 percent of 100003, while 1 is approximately 33 percent of 3. So, does this mean 100001 is more "similar" to 100003 than 1 is to 3? Is this what the coefficient of variation signifies?
PS: Please don't delete the question, I have seen there might be possible duplicates of this according to somebody, but I went through them and they didn't address my doubt. Hence this question. Apologies for the trouble caused.

You've answered your own question at least partly. Your two examples show the same SD but variation expressed relative to each mean is quite different. Sometimes SD / mean is a good way to express that but not always. Contrary to your request I can't see anything here that isn't addressed in previous threads.

@NickCox that didn't adress my doubt. I couldn't understand them

The duplicate does address the question as you have asked it and it does so in many good ways from many perspectives in both technical and non-technical terms.  To help us understand you and respond to your doubt, please describe your understanding of the duplicate and point to which specific part(s) you do not understand. // BTW, your question has not been "deleted:" you and everyone else can still see it.  It has been closed to give you time to clarify what you need, so that nobody leaps in and gives a possibly inappropriate answer.
